# error TS2794: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. Did you forget to include 'void' in your type argument to 'Promise'?

Tags: typescript, promise, resolve

In my project, I was using `Typescript@4.0.3` and it was working fine, but now I updated its version to latest `Typescript@4.1.3` and it is giving me a lot of errors. I am unable to find anything in documentations and not getting any Idea how to resolve this issue.

here is my code:

```
dbPool.query(`DELETE FROM table WHERE Id='${Id}'`, () => resolve())
```

Another one is:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.redis.SET(addr, resp, () => resolve())
})
```

These both are giving me error:

> error TS2794: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. Did you forget to include 'void' in your type argument to 'Promise'?

Any idea what should I pass in `resolve()` to resolve this issue??

Comment: Why do you want to resolve your promise with `undefined`? Does `this.red.SET` have no result?

Comment: This is an old code, and I really don't know what is happening in there. I just made a little change and due to typescript version conflict, now I am unable to make a build.

Comment: sorry a typo here,  that was not red, it is redis

Answer (score 208, accepted):

The standard argument for `resolve` in your case is `unknown`, which means that an argument is required;

If you don't want `resolve` to be taking any arguments you can explicitly set the generic type of `Promise` to `void`;

```
return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.red.SET(addr, resp, () => resolve())
})
```

Comment: what's the difference between Promise<undefined> and Promise<void> ?? and which one is better?

Comment: @NullPointer undefined is still a value, thus requiring an argument. void is just nothing at all